# Return Complete List of Outlets with Latitude & Longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Let me begin by saying I don't know how to code, unless you want to count STATA (which you don't)...

I have a project where I need the latitudes and longitudes of every Petrobas gas station in Brazil.

Google already has each one of these locations indexed and searchable... and they also have the latitude / longitude of each location.

I was wondering if there is a way to use the Google Maps API to return a list of each outlet, it's address and its Lat/long?

My best attempt at the code is as follows:

```
</: Hack mainframe: input_"Petrobas Brazil" 
           Output_"Store, Address, Lat, Long"
:end code/>
```

I think I may have missed a comma or something because the code doesn't work :/

Any help / advice / input would be greatly appreciated! Otherwise I will have to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) provides. You may choose from the following services whichever suits you best:

- **Geocoding** is the process of converting addresses (like a street address) into geographic coordinates (like latitude and longitude), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.

  Sample request:

  > `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY`
- **Reverse geocoding** is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address. The Google Maps Geocoding API's reverse geocoding service also lets you find the address for a given place ID.

  Sample request:

  > `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

In addition to that, I find it really helpful to go through the [developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests) for more information and examples.

Comment: What if I don't have a list of all the addresses I would like geocoded? Is there a way to have Google Maps list all the addresses? Company websites don't tend to be very good at this...